# Migrating auto generate primary key

Tags: android, android-room

How can I migrate a primary key field, which was not set to Auto generate before?
From

```
@PrimaryKey
private int id;
```

To

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate=true)
private int id;
```

Since Sqlite does not support altering columns, my only guess is to migrate the whole table as is and resetting the constraints.

Do I even have to migrate the database during the development process or can I just rebuild it, since my database will change rapidly, so I don't have to migrate every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to change your approach: add an unique identifier (UID) as alternative way to identify records.

You can define a UID with annotation `Entity` on your POJO.

```
@Entity(indices={@Index(value="uid", unique=true)})
publi class Pojo {
  ..
  public String uid;
  ..
}
```

When you insert a record in your database, you can define uid field using:

```
String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

You can use the UUID field to identify your records, in absolute way. When you migrate to a version to another, you don't work with the old ids, you can always work with UID.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I figured another way a few hours ago :) I located the database via the Device File Explorer in Data > Data > *PACKAGENAME* > databases > *DATABASENAME* and could delete it there. Then I started the project again and it rebuilt the database without any errors, this should do the trick during the development process.